clarification on publicDir and base in a vite/vue app
Just created a new vue/vite app with npm create vite@latest.  I'm trying to set up a public directory for my image assets, but the docs are a little ambiguous.  The vite docs at https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html say

The directory defaults to <root>/public, but can be configured via the publicDir option.
Note that:
You should always reference public assets using root absolute path - for example, public/icon.png should be referenced in source code as /icon.png.

It would be nice if they clarified that <root> is always the folder that contains index.html even though the entire app lives in the src folder and some parts of a vue app or other dependencies assumes that src is the root.  I had to do a bit of digging to find that.
But I think the docs are wrong about how you should reference the files, especially if you are setting a base href, as I am.  In my vite.config.ts I have
'base': '/myapp',
'publicDir': 'src/public'

If I follow the instructions and use <img src='/icon.png' /> to load repository-root/src/public/icon.png the file doesn't load.  I have to use <img src='icon.png' />.  And yes, I have to set my base to '/myapp' even though the instructions at https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base say

Absolute URL pathname, e.g. /foo/

If I use /myapp/ then the page complete fails to load and actually gives me an error in the console about pinia, so it seems to get hung up in my main.ts.  I also have to leave off slashes on the publicDir.  I think I tried all the combinations, but won't guarantee it, and only /path on the base, path/to/public on publicDir and path/to/image.png worked for me.
Here are the versions I'm using from package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.4.47",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0",
    "vuetify": "^3.5.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.24.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.8",
    "vite-plugin-vue-devtools": "^7.0.25",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.7"
  }

So am I just reading the instructions wrong/making wrong assumptions (like I did for <root>) ?  Or do using the base and publicDir options in the vite config change the syntax?

it would also be really nice if setting base in the config actually set the base href, because vite isn't always rewriting the urls correctly.  I wrote them as icon.png, but without a base-href in the html, it wasn't being served.
